Reference for isomorphism theorem for Banach spaces
Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces, and a linear continuous operator $T:X \rightarrow Y$ then we have that,
denote by $N =\text{ker }T$ and by $\text{Ran }T$ the closed range of T then,
$$
  X / N \cong \text{Ran }T.
$$
I have looked in Rudin and Yosida but I'm not able to find it, maybe because is elemmental.
I know there is a related question:
First isomorphism theorem for Banach Spaces
But it doesn't mention any book.

See theorem 1.7.14 in Megginson's book https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-0603-3
